# storing multiple values in single viewstate object

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi guy's here is one problem regarding asp.net state managenment.
I want to store three values into single viewstate.Is it possible to store in single or i will go for three viewstate variables.

the basic need is that,I am using gridview **rowcommand** event for finding three values.
and i wanted to use these values in **button_click** event.it is directely not possible so i prefer viewstate.

if any other way to do this you can post.I am new in .net development so please share some knowledge of you.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to put them in one variable?

Comment: Removed the `asp.net-mvc` tag from your question as there's no such notion of ViewState in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a class, and mark it with a Serializable attribute. Then make a list instance of that class and store it as 1 item in the viewstate. This is when you have a lot of values to store. However yours is a simple case I think:

```
[Serializable()]
class SomeData
{

    public string Value1 {get; set;}
    public string Value2 {get; set;}
    public string Value3 {get; set;}

}
```

Add to viewstate:

```
ViewState.Add("myData", new SomeData () {Value1 = "A", 
    Value2 = "B", 
    Value2 = "3"});
```

Retrieve back from ViewState on postback:

```
var data = (SomeData)ViewState["myData"];
Label1.Text = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", 
    data.Value1, data.Value2, data.Value3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any separator. For e.g.:

```
ViewState["items"] = item1 + "~" + item2 + "~" + item3
```

For retrieving values from ViewState, split the values by "~".

Comment: And when one of the items contains `~`?

Comment: @tomfanning I have already said in my answer that you can choose any seperator (as per your data & need).

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever separator you want. 
But your code would be a lot cleaner if you used three separate variables.

Let .net handle the viewstate. Using one variable seems like an unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario you don't need ViewState - you can store them in variables in the code behind because the rowcommand and button_click will both fire on the same post back. You only need to store items in ViewState if they're needed across post backs.

Comment: but the button is on Modelpopup extender after (button click on gridview)rowcommand  the model popup will open and there is Button on that popup(button_click).

Comment: Ok but I'm still not sure you need ViewState - couldn't you just loop through the gridview rows in the button_click? But if you can't I would go for three ViewState properties

Comment: @FrankJames example of a ViewState property is `private string Item1{get{ return (string) ViewState["Item1"];} set{ViewState["Item1"] = value;}}`